# Why does nested initializer_list cause memory leaks

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-leaks, initializer-list

Recently I've upgraded my project to Visual Studio 2013. Thus initializer_list feature is now available. I need to initialize test data in my unit tests. But I am getting memory leaks using nested initialize_lists.

```
#include <memory>
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

struct Test_Fixture
{
    Test_Fixture()
    :test_data({
        std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>(std::vector<int>{ 0, 1 }),
        std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>(std::vector<int>{ 2, 3, 4 })
    }) {}

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>>> test_data;
};

BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_CASE( testcase_1, Test_Fixture )
{
    BOOST_CHECK(true);
}
```

Output:

```
1>  Detected memory leaks!
1>  Dumping objects ->
1>  {1593} normal block at 0x0051A6E8, 8 bytes long.
1>   Data: <` C     > 60 F6 43 00 00 00 00 00 
1>  Object dump complete.
```

Comment: Maybe related to [this bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/807610/first-element-of-vector-is-destroyed-initializing-from-initializer-list)?

Comment: @DyP both bugs prevent me from using this feature. :( Thank you.

Comment: Can confirm the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a compiler bug:
[See here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/807419/initializer-lists-leaking-memory)

This feature doesn't like having classes as list items. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165166/double-delete-in-initializer-list-vs-2013)