# global static const shared_ptr is strangely stealed and deleted by another shared_ptr's destructor, why?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, move-semantics

I was writting a file manager and saw reproducible crashes when I open a folder twice.
To mininize the related code:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <boost/smart_ptr.hpp>

namespace myns {
    using std::shared_ptr;
}

class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

class Derived_1 : public Base {
public:
    ~Derived_1() {} // breakpoint 1
};

myns::shared_ptr<Derived_1> Derived_1_ptr() {
    static const myns::shared_ptr<Derived_1> r{new Derived_1};
    return r;
}

class Derived_2 : public Base {};
myns::shared_ptr<Derived_2> Derived_2_ptr() {
    static const myns::shared_ptr<Derived_2> r{new Derived_2};
    return r;
}
std::vector<myns::shared_ptr<Base>> all_derived_ptrs() {
    return{Derived_1_ptr(), Derived_2_ptr()}; // no breakpoint
}

void test_1() {
    all_derived_ptrs(); // breakpoint 2
    all_derived_ptrs(); // breakpoint 3
}

void test_2() {
    {
        std::vector<myns::shared_ptr<Base>> t{Derived_1_ptr(), Derived_2_ptr()};
    }
    {
        std::vector<myns::shared_ptr<Base>> t{Derived_1_ptr(), Derived_2_ptr()};
    }
}

int main() {
    test_1();
    return 0;
}
```

Derived_1_ptr() and Derived_2_ptr() are in fact global variables that solve the [initialization order problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335369/finding-c-static-initialization-order-problems).

With these code:

1. Compile and run without debugging in Visual Studio 2013, crash (Win8: program stopped working).
2. Change main to test_2(), crash again.
3. Change back to test_1, set 3 breakpoint as above and debug. It first break at #2, then #1, then #3, then a dialog popup saying "has triggered a breakpoint" and it break in ntdll while "next statement" is at `no breakpoint`.
4. Change to test_2 again, set a breakpoint right after the first `t` is constructed, and look at `t` in debug window. `t[0]` has 1 strong ref and `t[1]` has 2 strong refs.

So I can infer that when the first vector is constructed, `Derived_2_ptr()` is correctly copied (++reference_count), while `Derived_1_ptr()` seems to be stealed (moved?) from the static const r (reference_count is still 1). When the first vector is destroyed `Derived_2_ptr()` correctly performs --reference_count and is still alive, but `Derived_1_ptr()` loses its only reference and dies before the second vector is created (it is a global static variable!).

Why? **Can move constructor be applied to `static const` things?**

I try changing the return type of `Derived_x_ptr()` to `const myns::shared_ptr<Derived_x>&` or `myns::shared_ptr<Base>`, and both work correctly.

Also, if I remove Derived_2_ptr() and make all_derived_ptrs `return{Derived_1_ptr(), nullptr}`, Derived_1_ptr() magically works.

If I use boost::shared_ptr instead, the problem is hidden (no program stopped dialog) but ~Derived_1() is still called too early.

What is going on here? Does standard allows this kind of move? Is it a Microsoft-specific thing, or a VS2013-specific thing (I don't have another C++11 compiler)? Any ideas?

Comment: I'm seeing a bad call to the std::initializer_list constructor, the begin argument is good but the end argument is uninitialized.

Comment: @HansPassant: Did you mean std::initializer_list::initializer_list(const _Elem *_First_arg, const _Elem *_Last_arg)? Yes if I breakpoint here _Last_arg is uninitialized, but I think it doesn't matter because [_First_arg, _Last_arg) is a range: _First_arg is Derived_1, _First_arg+1 is Derived_2, and _First_arg+2==_Last_arg (marks the end of the range)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be seeing this bug: [initializer_list handling broken, destructors of temporary objects called twice](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/791137/initializer-list-handling-broken-destructors-of-temporary-objects-called-twice). Or this one (could be one and the same): [Double delete in initializer_list vs 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165166/double-delete-in-initializer-list-vs-2013)