# Initialize a map with map-values

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, initializer-list

I want to initialize a `map` with `map`-values in the following way:

```
std::map<int, std::map<int, int>> map =
{
    { 1, { { 1, 0 }, { 2, 1 } } },
    { 2, { { 1, 1 }, { 2, 0 } } },
};
```

While this compiles without any error or warning, it raises an exception stating "*map/set iterators incompatible*". If I remove the second pair, i.e. `{ 2, { { 1, 1 }, { 2, 0 } } }`, no exception is raised and `map` contains one pair with key `1` and a map containing the pairs `(1, 0)` and `(2, 1)` as its value.

I'm sure there is a quite good reason for this (at first glance) somehow strange behavior.

---

### Solution

Nope, there's no good reason. It turned out to be one of the beautiful bugs in Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: remove ',' comma at the end.

Comment: It [works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef37b18f0a8f1c83)... perhaps it is a bug with your compiler.

Comment: @40two trailing commas are fine in braced-init-lists.

Comment: @ecatmur I know they are OK, they aren't good habit though.

Comment: @Mankarse I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: hehe, the OP is right it breaks in VS. It's a bug. VS2013 has several issues with nested initializers lists. I think is fixed in update 1.

Comment: @40two But I LOVE trailing commas!

Comment: @0xbadf00d LOL it's OK with me, I don't want to keep lovers apart.

Comment: Duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23965565/how-to-do-nested-initializer-lists-in-visual-c-2013) (but I can't mark it as such because that question has no answers). @40two There's no *bad habit* in using trailing commas. They're quite convenient because you don't have to modify existing lines when adding a new initial value. Also extremely handy if you're ever writing a tool to autogenerate initial values.

Comment: @40two: Beyond convenience, I'd say that they are a *good* practice, as they allow line-based diffs to be significantly cleaner.

Comment: If this is the answer, please answer your own question. With details if possible.

Answer (score 0):

did you tried with c++11 option?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
  std::map<int, std::map<int, int>> map =
    {
      { 1, { { 1, 0 }, { 2, 1 } } },
      { 2, { { 1, 1 }, { 2, 0 } } },
    };

  auto t = map[1];
  std::cout << t[1] << std::endl;
  std::cout << t[2] << std::endl;

  auto t2 = map[2];
  std::cout << t2[1] << std::endl;
  std::cout << t2[2] << std::endl;

  std::cout << "--------------" << std::endl;
  std::cout << map[1][1] << std::endl;
  std::cout << map[1][2] << std::endl;
  std::cout << map[2][1] << std::endl;
  std::cout << map[2][2] << std::endl;
}
```